# Is testing for Repository class without any code of my own necessary?

Tags: java, testing, repository

I'm trying to learn about writing test for my Spring boot application and I ran into this question.

I don't have any logic of my own on my Repository class which extends JpaRepository. Do I still really need testing for this? What's the point and what exactly am I testing for? JPA already implemented every methods I'm using and those are already qualified.

It's hard to find a well organized or official docs for the answer of this question.

#### TodoRepository.java

```java
package com.todolist.repository;

import com.todolist.model.entity.TodoEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<TodoEntity, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the test pyramid and whether there is anything in ToDoEntity that needs to be covered by unit tests

You could then decide whether you’d test such repositories (containing your custom entities) via unit tests or in integration tests where you’d test the operations of To Do via an application or API endpoint

You can unit test JPA repositories. plenty of examples on google if you search for testing JPA entities

I’ve previously opted for the integration test approach as unit testing every jpa repo / entity can seem like overkill especially when the entities are simple

Comment: The very first line you wrote, now I think I see a point for testing repository class. And I've never heard about the test pyramid but now that you mentioned and I should dig into this. thank you so much